# MS SQL: Distinct and unordered by first column and ordered by second column

Tags: sql-server

Sorry for the first version :( 
 See below my real example :

```
declare @myTable table(
FilterName varchar(100)
, FilterOption varchar(100))

insert into @myTable values
 ('Naam Adverteerder', 'kras'),('Branche', 'toerisme en vrije tijd'),('Mediumtype', 'krant'),('Formaat', 'kwart page (1/4)'),('Positie', 'linker (pagina)'),('Soort Uiting', 'print'),('Type', 'post-test'),('Ad', 'ja'),('Ad', 'nee'),('De Volkskrant', 'nee'),('De Volkskrant', 'ja'),('Trouw', 'nee'),('Trouw', 'ja'),('Het Parool', 'nee'),('Het Parool', 'ja'),('Bn Destem', 'nee'),('Bn Destem', 'ja'),('Brabants Dagblad', 'nee'),('Brabants Dagblad', 'ja'),('De Gelderlander', 'nee'),('De Gelderlander', 'ja'),('De Stentor', 'nee'),('De Stentor', 'ja'),('Tubantia', 'nee'),('Tubantia', 'ja'),('Eindhovens Dagblad', 'nee'),('Eindhovens Dagblad', 'ja'),('Pzc', 'nee'),('Pzc', 'ja'),('Magazine', 'nee'),('Magazine', 'ja'),('Hah', 'nee'),('Hah', 'ja'),('Ad nl', 'nee'),('Ad nl', 'ja'),('Vk nl', 'nee'),('Vk nl', 'ja'),('Tr nl', 'nee'),('Tr nl', 'ja'),('Parool nl', 'nee'),('Parool nl', 'ja'),('Regionale Website', 'nee'),('Regionale Website', 'ja'),('Week', '41'),('Kwartaal', '4'),('Jaar', '2016'),('Sample', 'breed'),('Naam Adverteerder', 'bol.com')

select FilterName, FilterOption
from    @myTable
```

The question is if possible an SQL query which returns the FilterNames in inserted order as first column, and int the second column all the filter options sorted A-Z ? 
[OUTPUT EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5b5O.png)

I'm using the following query :

```
    SELECT FilterName,FilterOption
    FROM(
      SELECT FilterName,FilterOption, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY FilterName,FilterOption  ORDER BY FilterOption) AS rn 
    FROM   @myTable
   )A 
   WHERE rn = 1
   ORDER BY (2)
```

Comment: Are you expecting us to guess what your question is? _Edit:_ If you want a ready to use query then you are on the wrong site...

Comment: Requirement: [empty] What i have tried: [empty] Question quality [poor]

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. How are we meant to determine that, for instance, the `UU` rows are to come between the `AA` and `BB` rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
declare @myTable table(
    FilterName varchar(10)
    , FilterOption varchar(10)
)
insert into @myTable values
    ('XX', 'ccc'),('XX', 'ccc'),('XX', 'acc')
    ,('XX', 'bbx'),('XX', 'ccc'),('AA', 'fff'),('AA', 'bbb')
    ,('AA', 'fff'),('AA', 'acd'),('UU', 'uff'),('UU', 'acf')
    ,('UU', 'uff'),('BB', 'bff'),('BB', 'bff'),('BB', 'aff')
    ,('BB', 'aff'),('BB', 'xff'),('BB', 'xff'),('BB', 'aff')

select
    FilterName, FilterOption
from
    @myTable
group by FilterName, FilterOption
order by min(FilterOption) over (partition by FilterName), FilterOption
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, i believe you want a custom sorting. one of the ways is to use case statement

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (FilterName VARCHAR(10),   FilterOption VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('XX', 'ccc'),
('XX', 'ccc'),
('XX', 'acc'),
('XX', 'bbx'),
('XX', 'ccc'),
('AA', 'fff'),
('AA', 'bbb'),
('AA', 'fff'),
('AA', 'acd'),
('UU', 'uff'),
('UU', 'acf'),
('UU', 'uff'),
('BB', 'bff'),
('BB', 'bff'),
('BB', 'aff'),
('BB', 'aff'),
('BB', 'xff'),
('BB', 'xff'),
('BB', 'aff');

;WITH SORTING AS (SELECT DISTINCT
*,
CASE 
WHEN FilterName='XX' THEN 1
WHEN FilterName='AA' THEN 2
WHEN FilterName='UU' THEN 3
WHEN FilterName='BB' THEN 4
ELSE 5 END AS SORT
FROM @T
)
SELECT
FilterName, FilterOption
FROM SORTING
ORDER BY  SORT, FilterOption
```

OUTPUT

```
FilterName  FilterOption
XX  acc
XX  bbx
XX  ccc
AA  acd
AA  bbb
AA  fff
UU  acf
UU  uff
BB  aff
BB  bff
BB  xff
```